# Web3 ExtraDataLength Error on the Binance Smart Chain using python

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to pull the transactions that took place on a specific block, and I get stuck here:

```
from web3 import Web3

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

block = web3.eth.get_block('latest')

web3.exceptions.ExtraDataLengthError: The field extraData is 97 bytes, but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA chain. Refer to http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority for more details.
```

I want to get the transactions that a certain wallet address was involved in, and I have no idea why web3 isn't letting me pull that from the bsc node.

Answer (score 7):

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('127.0.0.1:100500'))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

Comment: Had the same problem with Avalanche, the solution works. My only doubt is that  Avalanche uses POS not POA

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should help:

```
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'web3' has no attribute 'middleware_onion' -- Could you elaborate?

Comment: looks like new version moved some things around. Probably the answer above is more updated